# Installed Metasploit on Windows, 3 Ruby processes spinning CPU at 100%

Tags: ruby

So, this is my very first encounter with both Ruby and Metasploit.

I have used the default installer for 64bit Windows7 for Metasploit. Installer finished, but 3 Ruby processes appeared, that were eating up ~100% CPU.

Restarted my computer, and as soon as Windows logs on, 3 Ruby processes start again at 100% CPU.

I have found a couple pages related, but they were either Linux/Unix OS or very old.

I am still Googling for solution, but I would appreciate if somebody here could give me a beginner level explanation on what to do with Ruby.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue. Simple fix. You have to change the services to manual startup

**Step by Step:**

start menu > type **Services**

(you want services not component services)

Now there will be 4 metasploit services

- metasploit pro service
- metasploit thin service
- metasploit worker
- metasploitPostgreSQl

**right click** on each service and goto **Properties**

change **Startup Type**  to **Manual**

restart computer to check.

Note: To start service local the 'services' folder in hte metasploit directory.

Honestly, if this is your first time. I'd recommend using Armitage a few times to get a visually understand of what's going on. then using Metasploit CLI with linux first before moving to the windows version.